# How to manage a json file when appending new data

Tags: python, json

i) I have a class `User`
let's say I got the objects now and I put them in a dictionary and appended them in a json file just like how this code explains

```
import json

dic = {
    'name': User.Name,
    'level': User.Level,
    "id": User.ID
}

with open('UserList.json', 'a') as fp:
    json.dump(dic, fp, indent=2)
```

ii) the json file will list the data like this:

```
{
  "name": "Moustafa",
  "level": "normal_user",
  "id": "1"
}
```

iii) The problem is when there is another data the json file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "Moustafa",
  "level": "normal_user",
  "id": "1"
}{
  "name": "Moustafa",
  "level": "normal_user",
  "id": "1"
}
```

iv) The braces "{" are overlapping.
I want the json file to look like this:

```
[
 {
   "name": "Moustafa",
   "level": "normal_user",
   "id": "1"
 },
 {
  "name": "Moustafa",
  "level": "normal_user",
  "id": "1"
 }
```

v) THE BIG QUESTION IS: is the iii) version of the json file format usable if want to convert the data back to a class object again or do I have to turned it into the iv) version

Comment: You need to read whole file and add new item then write it to file again.

Comment: Can I do that even though the code is almost always running with a while loop?

Comment: if you do that in every cycle disk IO will be used a lot. you just have to open the file when there is a change, then you can read, change and write the file.

Comment: So ultimately you're asking how to use malformed JSON? I guess the answer would be to avoid it if possible. But if you're stuck with malformed data, you could possibly use regex to get it into shape. If you want to [edit] and clarify, I could post an answer. Check out [ask] for tips on writing a good title.